# Setting Busy cursor for the html page with iframes having flex applications

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I have a html page with 4 iframes out of these 4 one is a static html page and other 3 are html generated by flex. I have a button and list in one of the flex applications and the list will be populated on click of the button. Now what I want is to have a custom busy cursor to appear on the top of the whole html page until the list gets populated.

Please tell me if its possible with an example.

Thanks in advance

Prahsant Dubey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you can not have flex control the cursor over areas of the page not part of the flash player. But here's what you can do. Call external javascript from flex, then use JS to do the cursor.

Here's how to call JS from flex:
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/flex-javascript-basics-using-externalinterface

and here's how to do a JS cursor:
http://www.webcodingtech.com/javascript/change-cursor.php

Comment: hi thanks for your help. I will try the way you have told.Thanks